# Как добавить функцию итилитарным методом через Chart.elements.Rectangle.prototype.backgroundColor?

Tags: vue.js, диаграммы

Почему если запускать функцию для отрисовки фона графика в хуке mounted - всё будет работать, а если кинуть её в другой js файл и импортировать

import Chart from 'chart.js';
import { chartBackgroundGradientRender, chartDrawDashedLine } from '@/utils/vps';

Chart.elements.Rectangle.prototype.backgroundColor = chartBackgroundGradientRender;

тогда всё перестает работать

Функция отрисовки фона -

```
export const chartBackgroundGradientRender = function () {
this.gradient = this.$refs.chart.getContext('2d')
.createLinearGradient(0, 0, 0, 450);
this.gradient.addColorStop(0, '#EAECF8');
 this.gradient.addColorStop(1, 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0)');

this.chartInstance.data.datasets[0].backgroundColor = this.gradient;
this.chartInstance.update();
```

};